# Remove multiple whitespaces

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace, whitespace

I'm getting `$row['message']` from a MySQL database and I need to remove all whitespace like `\n` `\t` and so on.

```
$row['message'] = "This is   a Text \n and so on \t     Text text.";
```

should be formatted to:

```
$row['message'] = 'This is a Text and so on Text text.';
```

I tried:

```
 $ro = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ',$row['message']);
 echo $ro;
```

but it doesn't remove `\n` or `\t`, just single spaces. Can anyone tell me how to do that?

Comment: The newline and tab characters are in single quotes, so you want them literal?

Comment: I fixed the quoting of the code sectin with the \n and \t by changing it to double-quotes.

Answer (score 466):

You need:

```
$ro = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $row['message']);
```

You are using `\s\s+` which means whitespace(space, tab or newline) followed by one or more whitespace. Which effectively means replace two or more whitespace with a single space.

What you want is replace one or more whitespace with single whitespace, so you can use the pattern  `\s\s*` or `\s+` (recommended)

Comment: his method is better than this: why would you replace one space with one space?

Comment: He also wants \n and \t to be replaced with space. Now his pattern does not match these, say for $x = "does\nthis\twork"; The OP wants all whitespace to be replaced with a single space.

Comment: @codaddict, how we can keep \n and remove all other multiple space and tabs from the string? please help me

Comment: Can you be more specific why "\s+" is recommended?

Comment: Note that in PHP `\s` not including "vertical tab" `chr(11)`. To include it too you need to use `space` character class: `[[:space:]]+` http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php

Comment: keep in mind that this will also replace newlines `\r\n` with a single space ` `

Comment: $row['message'] = 18; // $ro is null.

Comment: @WHK `preg_replace()` requires the third parameter to be either a string or an array full of strings. Otherwise, it will return `null`, meaning an error occured. `$row['message'] = 18; // $ro = null` **while** `$row['message'] = '18'; // $ro = '18'` **and** `$row['message'] = (string) 18; // $ro = '18'`

Comment: I want to remove spaces at the beginning or at the end of the text. If the string is `'    Text with a lot of spaces    '`, it returns `' Text with a lot of spaces '`. I expect `'Text with a lot of spaces'`.

Comment: I tried using this method, which works, except that instead of " " I get `&nbsp;`. Normally, this wouldn't matter, but I'm exporting the result text to an Excel spreadsheet, and those `&nbsp;` are showing up in the spreadsheet cell. It's bad because the spreadsheet cell text is going to be used to print mailing labels.

Comment: Here's a method that will also remove `&nbsp;` preg_replace(array('/\s{2,}|&nbsp;/', '/[\t\n]/'), ' ', $str)`

Comment: @codaddict , nice job, thank you, with keeping this regex pattern, is there a way to get rid of all spaces at the right & and the left of the string? for example, " a b c ", would be "a b c", I know we could use trim($ro), but it would be nice to have it in regex

Answer (score 80):

```
<?php
$str = "This is  a string       with
spaces, tabs and newlines present";

$stripped = preg_replace(array('/\s{2,}/', '/[\t\n]/'), ' ', $str);

echo $str;
echo "\n---\n";
echo "$stripped";
?>
```

This outputs

```
This is  a string   with
spaces, tabs and newlines present
---
This is a string with spaces, tabs and newlines present
```

Answer (score 18):

```
preg_replace('/[\s]+/mu', ' ', $var);
```

`\s` already contains tabs and new lines, so this above regex appears to be sufficient.

Comment: Square brackets aren't needed here because there's only one thing inside them.  The `/m` wont have an effect as there are no `^` or `$` anchors and the `/u` won't have any effect except to slow it down slightly and die if the input string is not valid UTF-8 (it doesn't affect what `\s` matches, but it would affect `\pZ`).

Answer (score 15):

simplified to one function:

```
function removeWhiteSpace($text)
{
    $text = preg_replace('/[\t\n\r\0\x0B]/', '', $text);
    $text = preg_replace('/([\s])\1+/', ' ', $text);
    $text = trim($text);
    return $text;
}
```

based on Danuel O'Neal answer.

Answer (score 10):

```
$str='This is   a Text \n and so on Text text.';
print preg_replace("/[[:blank:]]+/"," ",$str);
```

Comment: This is the one that worked for me the best. Also, I would add trim to erase whitespace in the beginning and end of string

Comment: @Dziamid You can do it with trim(preg_replace(...))

Answer (score 10):

I can't replicate the problem here:

```
$x = "this    \n \t\t \n    works.";
var_dump(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $x));
// string(11) "this works."
```

I'm not sure if it was just a transcription error or not, but in your example, you're using a single-quoted string. `\n` and `\t` are only treated as new-line and tab if you've got a double quoted string. That is:

```
'\n\t' != "\n\t"
```

*Edit*: as Codaddict pointed out, `\s\s+` won't replace a single tab character. I still don't think using `\s+` is an efficient solution though, so how about this instead:

```
preg_replace('/(?:\s\s+|\n|\t)/', ' ', $x);
```

Comment: +1, True. For a string with plenty of single spaces (which usually is the case) it is inefficient to replace a space with space.

Comment: @coaddict: to test your hypothesis, i wrote a quick script to run through 1000 of each replacement and check the timing of each.  For the string **'+1, True. For a string with plenty of single spaces (which usually is the case) it is inefficient to replace a space with space. –  codaddict Feb 24 \'10 at 13:32'**, one thousand **\s+** preg_replace() calls took 0.010547876358032 seconds, and one thousand **(?:\s\s+|\n|\t)** preg_replace() calls took 0.013049125671387, making it almost 30% slower.

Comment: You may want to add "\r" to that last example as some computers do use a single "\r" on its own (Apple Mac?)

Answer (score 6):

```
preg_replace('/(\s\s+|\t|\n)/', ' ', $row['message']);
```

This replaces all tabs, all newlines and all combinations of multiple spaces, tabs and newlines with a single space.

Comment: `\t` & `\n` are already included in `\s` so your regex is **exactly** the same than `\s\s+` that is better written `\s{2,}` just like @Alex Polo [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3127205/372239)

Comment: I needed the same functionality as in the original question only without replacing the single space with single space character and this is the solution

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php
#This should help some newbies
# REGEX NOTES FROM DANUEL
# I wrote these functions for my own php framework
# Feel Free to make it better
# If it gets more complicated than this. You need to do more software engineering/logic.
# (.)  // capture any character
# \1   // if it is followed by itself
# +    // one or more

class whitespace{

    static function remove_doublewhitespace($s = null){
           return  $ret = preg_replace('/([\s])\1+/', ' ', $s);
    }

    static function remove_whitespace($s = null){
           return $ret = preg_replace('/[\s]+/', '', $s );
    }

    static function remove_whitespace_feed( $s = null){
           return $ret = preg_replace('/[\t\n\r\0\x0B]/', '', $s);
    }

    static function smart_clean($s = null){
           return $ret = trim( self::remove_doublewhitespace( self::remove_whitespace_feed($s) ) );
    }
}
$string = " Hey   yo, what's \t\n\tthe sc\r\nen\n\tario! \n";
echo whitespace::smart_clean($string);
```

Comment: static function remove_whitespace is for what reason? You define but never use it.

Comment: These each have their use but none of these would achieve what the question asks for which is to replace multiple consecutive whitespace with just one.  Your "remove_doublewhitespace" would only replace multiple of *the same* whitespace character, so it would replace "\n\n\n" with a ' ', but it would not do anything to " \r\n"

Answer (score 4):

Without preg_replace()

```
$str = "This is   a Text \n and so on \t     Text text.";
$str = str_replace(["\r", "\n", "\t"], " ", $str);
while (strpos($str, "  ") !== false)
{
    $str = str_replace("  ", " ", $str);
}
echo $str;
```

Answer (score 3):

This is what I would use:

a. Make sure to use double quotes, for example:

```
$row['message'] = "This is   a Text \n and so on \t     Text text.";
```

b. To remove extra whitespace, use:

```
$ro = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $row['message']); 
echo $ro;
```

It may not be the fastest solution, but I think it will require the least code, and it should work. I've never used mysql, though, so I may be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

All you need is to run it as follows:

```
echo preg_replace('/\s{2,}/', ' ', "This is   a Text \n and so on \t     Text text."); // This is a Text and so on Text text.
```

Answer (score 2):

I use this code and pattern:

```
preg_replace('/\\s+/', ' ',$data)

$data = 'This is   a Text 
   and so on         Text text on multiple lines and with        whitespaces';
$data= preg_replace('/\\s+/', ' ',$data);
echo $data;
```

You may test this on http://writecodeonline.com/php/

Comment: It works with me even in mariaDB in this query:

`SELECT search_able, REGEXP_REPLACE (search_able,"\\s+",' ') FROM book where id =260`

So Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

On the truth, if think that you want something like this:

```
preg_replace('/\n+|\t+|\s+/',' ',$string);
```

Answer (score 1):

this will replace multiple tabs with a single tab

```
preg_replace("/\s{2,}/", "\t", $string);
```

Answer (score -4):

Without preg_replace, with the help of loop.

```
<?php

$str = "This is   a Text  and so on      Text text.";
$str_length = strlen($str);
$str_arr = str_split($str);
for ($i = 0; $i < $str_length; $i++) {
    if (isset($str_arr[$i + 1])
       && $str_arr[$i] == ' '
       && $str_arr[$i] == $str_arr[$i + 1]) {
       unset($str_arr[$i]);
    } 
    else {
      continue;
    }
}

 echo implode("", $str_arr) ; 

 ?>
```