# Replacing excess whitespaces

Tags: php

I need to remove excess whitespaces from my players usernames in my application (more than once space between letters) and replace them with a single whitespace.  I do not mind users having a single whitespace, but I need to remove multiple whitespaces next to each other.  Currently I achieve it this way:

```
$replace_array=array('  ','   ','    ','     ','      ','       ','        ','             ','          ','           ','            ','             ','              ','               ');
$fill_array=array('','','','','','','','','','','','','','');

$user_name=str_replace($replace_array,$fill_array,trim($_POST['name']));
$user_name=preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/','',$user_name);
```

That seems entirely unnecessary to remove excess whitespaces.  Does, perhaps, the preg_replace function already handle excess whitespaces?  If not, what should I do to simplify this part of my code.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [remove multiple whitespaces in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326125/remove-multiple-whitespaces-in-php)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $string);
```

Comment: How would I combine my current preg_replace function with this one?  I need to study this function a bit more.

Comment: `$user_name = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $user_name);`, then do the second preg_replace as usual. mixing regexes that have different purposes will usually only end up biting you in the butt, so keep them separate.

Comment: @Phillip better use you regexp first then this regexp. or "aaa & aaa" will fail

Answer (score 1):

find 1 or more space and replace by 1 space:

```
preg_replace('/\s+/',' ',$user_name)
```

Also you can use 1 preg-replace statement

```
$user_name=preg_replace('/([^a-zA-Z0-9 ]|\s+)/','',$user_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

try preg_replace like this:

```
preg_replace('/\s{2,}/', ' ', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

my understanding is that simply using `str_replace('  ', '')` will fix your issue.  It replaces multiple occurances of a space.  Also have you tried using ltrim?