# How to remove white spaces with php

Tags: php

Here is an example of text taken from database and displayed on the page:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris etc....
```

What to do to make the text below to looks like

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
```

I'm trying to remove all unnecessary white spaces and new lines. I have tested with trim() end str_replace, but I did not get the result that I want.

Comment: Do you want to remove `Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris etc....` as well?

Comment: No. Just white spaces and new lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Might this question help? [Remove multiple whitespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326125/remove-multiple-whitespaces-in-php)

From the top rated answer written by codaddict:

```
$ro = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ',$row['message']);
```

> You are using \s\s+ which means whitespace(space, tab or newline) followed by one or more whitespace. Which effectively means replace two or more whitespace with a single space. What you want is replace one or more whitespace with single whitespace, so you can use the pattern \s\s* or \s+ (recommended)

Answer (score 3):

This will remove all the newlines within your string:

```
$str = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $str);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$str = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $str);
```

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

```
<?php
$str = 'foo   o';
$str = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $str);
// This will be 'foo o' now
echo $str;
?>
```

Or you can chop string with explode by CRLF, and then trim.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
$string = 'Lorem ipsum... etc';
$string = preg_replace('/\s+/',' ',$string);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `trim` and `preg_replace`:

```
$string = trim( preg_replace( '/[\s\s \s]+/', ' ', $string ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use $str = preg_replace("/\s\s+/", " ", $str); for spaces

$your_string = str_replace("\r\n\r\n"," ",$your_string); for new lines.