# preg_replace non-alpha, leave single whitespaces

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

As the title reads, I'm trying to replace all non-alpha characters and replace all double (or more) white spaces to a single one. I simply can't get around the white spaces stuff.

So far my `preg_replace` line:

```
$result = trim( preg_replace( '/\s+/', '', strip_tags( $data->parent_label ) ) );
```

*Note: The `strip_tags` and `trim` is needed.*

---

*EDIT:* This is what I came up with:

```
/**
 * Removes all non alpha chars from a menu item label
 * Replaces double and more spaces into a single whitespace
 * 
 * @since 0.1
 * @param (string) $item
 * @return (string) $item
 */
public function cleanup_item( $item )
{
    // Regex patterns for preg_replace()
    $search = [
        '@<script[^>]*?>.*?</script>@si', // Strip out javascript 
        '@<style[^>]*?>.*?</style>@siU',  // Strip style tags properly 
        '@<[\/\!]*?[^<>]*?>@si',          // Strip out HTML tags
        '@<![\s\S]*?–[ \t\n\r]*>@',       // Strip multi-line comments including CDATA
        '/\s{2,}/',
        '/(\s){2,}/',
    ];
    $pattern = [
        '#[^a-zA-Z ]#', // Non alpha characters
        '/\s+/',        // More than one whitespace
    ];
    $replace = [
        '',
        ' ',
    ];
    $item = preg_replace( $search, '', html_entity_decode( $item ) );
    $item = trim( preg_replace( $pattern, $replace, strip_tags( $item ) ) );

    return $item;
}
```

Maybe the last `strip_tags()` isn't necessary. It's just there to be sure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326125/remove-multiple-whitespaces-in-php

Comment: @hafichuk Yea, if you only consider the title. As this would have exceeded the title lenght, the `trim` and `strip_tags` were left out, as they're already present in the code line. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$patterns = array (
  '/\W+/', // match any non-alpha-numeric character sequence, except underscores
  '/\d+/', // match any number of decimal digits
  '/_+/',  // match any number of underscores
  '/\s+/'  // match any number of white spaces
);

$replaces = array (
  '', // remove
  '', // remove
  '', // remove
  ' ' // leave only 1 space
);

$result = trim(preg_replace($patterns, $replaces, strip_tags( $data->parent_label ) ) );
```

...should do everything you want

Comment: I choose yours, as I was the most complete. Thanks. All +1

Answer (score 3):

You're telling it to replace spaces with blank, instead of a single space. Your second parameter to preg_replace is an empty string.

Answer (score 3):

> replace all double (or more) white spaces to a single one

For this, you need:

```
preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ', $subject)
```

In your version, you're eliminating all whitespace sequences with one or more elements.

Comment: I would change to '/\s+$/' but this is the correct answer.