# Remove extra blank spaces with PHP?

Tags: php

How do I turn `$string`:

```
"one    two              three"
```

into:

```
"one two three"
```

?

Comment: Duplicate of [preg_replace non-alpha, leave single whitespaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8329065/preg-replace-non-alpha-leave-single-whitespaces)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$str = "one    two              three";
$str = preg_replace('/ +/',' ',$str);
```

This replaces one or more spaces with a single space. It will also replace a single space with itself!! To improve it a bit:

```
$str = preg_replace('/ {2,}/',' ',$str);
```

which replaces a group of 2 or more consecutive spaces with single space.

Comment: I think `preg_replace('/s+/',' ',$str);` would be a little better.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$str = preg_replace("/[ ]{2,}/", " ", $str);
```