# PHP - Remove all tabs from string

Tags: php, tabs

I am able to remove all single tabs from a string:

```
// Copying and pasting the tab directly
$txt = str_replace("    ", "", $txt);
```

This only removes single tabs, but not double tabs.
I then tried this, thinking that "\t" would be sufficient to find the tabs:

```
$txt = preg_replace('/\t/', '', $txt);
```

However, it didn't work.  Can anyone offer something better?

Comment: possible duplicate of [remove multiple whitespaces in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326125/remove-multiple-whitespaces-in-php)

Comment: I'm not the best with RegExp but you can specify 1 tab or more with + sign

Comment: Seems to work for me: http://codepad.org/2u9ym1zB

Comment: Just use `preg_replace('/\t+/', '', $string)`..

Comment: There seems to be a misunderstanding, the question is related to the  `| |` (tab) character but `|    |` (4 spaces) characters were supplied in the example code. Since the source `$txt` value that was causing the issue was not provided, we can't verify the issue. The original code would have removed double tabs as 8 spaces as well, so seems OP may be wanting something like [`preg_replace('/\t| {4}/', '', $txt);`](https://3v4l.org/XcEAW) to replace either tab or 4 spaces together, the `+` is not needed unless start `^` or end `$` of pattern is also used.

Answer (score 78):

```
trim(preg_replace('/\t+/', '', $string))
```

Comment: Although similar to the post by Mr. Alien (which did not work), this one worked.

Comment: Watch out, the `trim()` part removes empty lines in the string if they appear in the beginning or the end.

Comment: Yes, you can just do `preg_replace('/\t+/', '', $string)`, but I typically found it useful to remove leading and ending white space as well.

Answer (score 11):

Try using this regular expression

```
$string = trim(preg_replace('/\t/g', '', $string));
```

This will trim out all tabs from the string ...

Comment: A tab is white space; but white space isn't always a tab

Comment: @MarkBaker According to you I should remove the `g` part?

Comment: no, the g part has absolutely no meaning.... I'm saying that \s includes spaces as well as tabs; OP is specifically asking about tabs

Comment: @MarkBaker Ya I got it, I thought you are telling me to remove the global

Comment: The `g` flag does not exist in PHP's PCRE implementation. The replace is always performed globally. Your solution as-is doesn't work!

Comment: This throws an error in php 7.3: "preg_replace(): No ending delimiter '/' found"

Answer (score 9):

this will remove all tabs in your variable $string

```
preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $string);
```

Comment: Wouldn't this just remove all spaces from a string as well?

Comment: `\s` is a shorthand for `[\t\r\n\f]`. It matches **new line**, **return** and **form feed** as well as **tabulator**.

Comment: replace any white space [\t\r\n\f] with single space, preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', trim($string));

Answer (score 4):

```
trim(preg_replace('/[\t|\s{2,}]/', '', $result))
```

Removes all tabs, including tabs created with multiple spaces

Comment: This also removes all regular spaces as well.  i added a space between the single quotes and that worked perfectly for me. It replaced all tabs, spaces, etc with a single space. I was trying to get text into a csv. I needed to strip out all of the tabs, double spaces and whatever because it was triggering a new column. This worked for me.  trim(preg_replace('/[\t|\s{2,}]/', ' ', $result))

Answer (score 3):

`$string = trim(preg_replace('/\t/', '', $string));`

This works for me. Remove the `g` of @Mr. Aliens answer.