# javascript JSON.parse can't parse \t from PHP json_encode

Tags: javascript, php, json, whitespace

This is my array to be encoded in PHP:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[70]
      public 'company' => string 'Mc.SUP s. r. o.' (length=15)
      public 'fullname' => string '     Jaroslav Antoň' (length=17)
      public 'id' => string '1956' (length=4)
      public 'editable' => string '1' (length=1)
```

The string result is:

```
'[{"company":"Mc.SUP s. r. o.","fullname":" \tJaroslav Anto\u0148","id":"1956","editable":"1"}]'
```

When trying to use Javascript JSON.parse I got this error message:
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: bad control character in string literal at line 1 column 56 of the JSON data

I investigated it and the problematic is **\t**.

Does somebody know the easy way how to extra escape it? Something like options in json_encode function. Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you need those `\t`'s in the values? Why dont you recursively strip all leading and trailing white spaces in the array?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP's json\_encode does not escape all JSON control characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048487/phps-json-encode-does-not-escape-all-json-control-characters)

Answer (score 1):

The `\t` is an escaped tab character do you really need that character for the `fullname` field? You should maybe remove the tab character before doing `json_encode` as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17176793/2030937