# Remove spaces before periods ? str_replace

Tags: php, str-replace

I'm trying to remove all spaces before period and commas from a text before i echo it.

The text could look like this , and have spaces all over . Bla bla bla...

Here is my code, although it successfully removes any ( ) and replaces it with "nothing":

```
$strip_metar = array('( )' => '', ' . ' => '. ', ' , ' => ', ');
$output_this = $text->print_pretty();
$output_this = str_replace(array_keys($strip_metar),
                           array_values($strip_metar),
                           $output_this);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: can you provide the sample string and the expected output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326125/remove-multiple-whitespaces-in-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove all spaces before period`.` and comma`,` you can pass arrays to the [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) function:

`$output_this = str_replace(array(' .',' ,'),array('.',','),$string);`

In the example you have provided, you will not strip spaces before a period, if the period is not followed by a space `' . '`

Answer (score 7):

This is just to expand on [Moylin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17954738/remove-spaces-before-periods-str-replace/17955001#17955001):

To make it into 1 query just do as such:

```
$output_this = preg_replace('/\s+(?=[\.,])/', '', $output_this);
```

Explanation of the regex:

\s matches a space

+ matches between 1 and infinity times.

(?= ) is a positive lookahead. This means "You have to find this AFTER the main group, but don't include it."

[ ] is a set of characters to match.

\. is an escaped period (Because . matches anything in regex)

and , is a comma!

Comment: Definite improvement, it's time i reread regex documentation.

Answer (score 1):

```
$output_this = preg_replace('/\s+\./', '.', $output_this);
$output_this = preg_replace('/\s+,/', ',', $output_this);
```

This should be accurate.

Sorry i'm not better to optimize this into a single query for you.
edit: removed $ for end of string, not sure you would want it that way.

Answer (score 0):

```
$content = "This is , some string .";
$content = str_replace( ' .', '.',$content);
$content = str_replace( ' ,', ',',$content);
echo $content;
```

Comment: This will output "This is, some string."