# str_replace leaving whitespace PHP

Tags: php, str-replace

This is my variable to be altered:

```
$last = 'Some string 1 foobar'
```

and my replace statement

```
$last = str_replace(['1', '2'], '', $last);
```

and finally the output

```
Some string   foobar
```

How do i get rid of the whitespace in between 'string' and 'foobar', my initial thought was that in my `str_replace` statement using `''` as the replacement would also remove the whitespace but it doesnt.

To clarify I want to know how to make it `Some string foobar` and not `Some stringfoobar`.

Comment: do this `$last = str_replace(['1 ', '2 '], '', $last);`

Comment: alternatively, get rid of all double spaces with this `preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $last);`

Comment: You should use a regex, then you can say the whitespace around the number is optional.

Comment: @Dimi wow thanks i didnt think that any extra space IN the actual string would affect it, thanks a lot for that. I only dont use reg ex because i read that when manipulating a string its best to use `str_replace()` plus im not too familiar with regular expressions

Comment: @YasminFrench generally speaking, arkascha's answer is probably better solutuon.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove multiple whitespaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326125/remove-multiple-whitespaces)

Comment: You can do `$last = str_replace(['1', '2','      '], ['','',' '], $last);` It remove first the 2 numbers then reduce all double spaces to a single space. The comment function will remove spaces here, so in the first single qoutes with space `' '` there a 2 spaces for real. comment will always remove it.

Comment: @StackOverflow I can not put 2 spaces into single quotes? `'     '`<- i have left more than one space here. (OK, the browser remove it here, in sourcecode ther are still there..arghhh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regular expression based approach is more flexible for such stuff:

```
<?php
$subject = 'Some string 1 foobar';
var_dump(preg_replace('/\d\s?/', '', $subject));
```

The output of above code is: `string(18) "Some string foobar"`

What does that do, how does it work? It replaces a *pattern*, not a fixed, literal string. Here the pattern is: any digit (`\d`) along with a single, *potentially* existing white space character (`\s?`).

---

A different, alternative approach would be that:

```
<?php
$subject = 'Some string 1 foobar';
var_dump(preg_replace('/(\s\d)+\s/', ' ', $subject));
```

This one replaces any sequence consisting of one or more occurrences of a digit preceded by a white space (`(\s\d)+`) along with a single white space by a single white blank character.

Comment: Right thanks for the explanation as well you cleared a few things up

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use `preg_replace` then you can do something like this.

```
$result = 'Some string 1 foobar';
$result = str_replace(['1', '2'], '', $result);
$result = str_replace('  ', ' ', $result);
```

However I have to admit that I like preg_replace solution more. Not sure about the benchmark though.

Comment: @arkascha Then say he used the wrong variable in the second str_replace and has an syntax error because of the `]`.

Comment: You still mix the variables `$last` and `$result`.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions I tried to motivate the poster to try the code himself.

Comment: Thanks for fixing things! Looks ok now and might indeed be faster than a regular expression based attempt.

Comment: @arkascha Thats a point, but sometimes its better to be direct :-) And comments like this will stay after the question is fixed. Can irritate others ;-) Thnx for notice the error in the first place :-)