# Trimming whitespaces, tabs and newlines in php

Tags: php

When I sanitize the input fields or text area I face a problem. When someone gave spaces and submit the form, my script accepts the form. But I want not to accept fields until there is not written at least a single character. My code is as follows.

Html

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <textarea name='text'></textarea>
    <input type='submit' name='submit'>
</form>
```

Php

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(isset($_POST['text']) && !empty($_POST['text'])){
          //do whatever but not accept white space
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `!empty($_POST['text'])` should do this. I can't see this failing. Your question isn't properly written; it's actually unclear.

Answer (score 1):

You can trim whatever you want, just by using

> trim()

Which removes characters from both sides of a string.
Documentaion: http://php.net/manual/bg/function.trim.php

Comment: If I wanted to trim multiple new lines than what I can do?

Comment: Suggest you to read this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326125/remove-multiple-whitespaces

Answer (score 0):

`trim` and `preg_replace` will do this easily

```
<?php
  echo $text = "  this is     niklesh       raut    ";
  echo "\n";
  $text = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ',$text);
  echo trim($text);
?>
```

live demo : https://eval.in/818137

OUTPUT :

```
  this is     niklesh       raut    
this is niklesh raut
```

With new line and tab : https://eval.in/818138

Answer (score -1):

You can either echo out your statement:

```
<?php
   if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(empty($_POST['text'])){
          echo "Please enter a value.";
    }
}
```

Or, add the `required` attribute to your input field.

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <textarea name='text' required></textarea>
    <input type='submit' name='submit'>
</form>
```