# Regex erase control characters except between words

Tags: php, arrays, regex

I got an array from a database with products and I want to split/seperate the large description text below in smaller chunks of product attribute name and value. Ultimately I'm striving for database normalization, as I'm currently trying to create a import tool for 2 different database designs.

The array I get from old product table:

```
        Array

            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [product_id] => 219
                        [product_description] =>
<table style="color:; text-align: left;">
<tr>
<td>
Processor:
</td>
<td>
        Intel Core 2 Duo - E8400
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Clock speed:
</td>
<td>
        3.0 GHz
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Memory:
</td>
<td>
        4 GB
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Hard disk:
</td>
<td>
        250 GB
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Video-adapter:
</td>
<td>
        VGA, Display
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Netwerk card:
</td>
<td>
        1000 Mbps LAN
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Optical drive:
</td>
<td>
        DVD-Rewriter
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Operating system:
</td>
<td>
        Windows 7 or 10 Pro
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Warranty:
</td>
<td>
        1 year
</td>
</tr>
</table>
                    )
            )
```

My code so far:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * from products WHERE product_status_id = '1' ORDER BY order_num ASC");
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$output = array();

$tdpattern = "!<td>(.*?)</td>!is";

foreach ($result as $key=>$val)  {
    preg_match_all($tdpattern, $val['product_description'], $result);
    foreach ($result as $key => $arr) {
        foreach ($arr as $key2 => $description) {
            $output[] = preg_replace('/\n^[\x0a\x20]+|[\x0a\x20]+$/','',$description);
        }
    }
}

// return $output to controller
```

As you can see below, the ouput shows multiple spaces infront of words but not between them, there are also newlines that should be erased. How can I erase all those control characters such as line feeds and whitespaces except 1 space between words for every array element so ideally it becomes like the layout at the bottom?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Processor
    [1] =>         IntelCore2-E5500
    [2] => Clockspeed
    [3] =>         2.93GHz
    [4] => Memory
    [5] =>         4GB
    [6] => Harddisk
    [7] =>         250GB
    [8] => Video-adapter
    [9] =>         VGA,Display
    [10] => Netwerkcard
    [11] =>         1000mbpsLAN
    [12] => Opticaldrive
    [13] =>         DVD-Rewriter
    [14] => Operatingsystem
    [15] =>         Windows7or10Pro
    [16] => Warranty
    [17] =>         2jaar
)
```

I wish to convert it to this layout:

```
[219] => array (
    [product_description] => array (
        [processor] => Intel Core 2 - E5500
        [clock speed] => 2.93 GHz
        [memory] => 2.93 GHz
        [hard disk] => 2.93 GHz
        [video adapter] => 2.93 GHz
        [network card] => DVD Rewriter
        [optical drive] => DVD Rewriter
        [operating system] => Windows 7 or 10 Pro
        [warranty] = > 2 years
    )
)
```

Some directions would be great, specifically how to improve the regex.

Comment: Regx is a poor choice for parsing "HTML", you'll have to use `preg_match_all`  I would make a tokenizer for it or use something like `PHPQuery`

Comment: Here is a Tokenizer/lexer I wrote for `Json` you can do similar for this. https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/MISC/blob/master/JasonDecoder.php  Maybe I will modify it for you...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove multiple whitespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326125/remove-multiple-whitespaces)

Comment: It's more complicated then just removing whitespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use regex to parse HTML, use [DomDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).

```
<?php
//...
$result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$dom_err = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom = new DOMDocument();

foreach ($result as $key => $val)  {

    // fix product_description
    $product_description = [];
    if (!empty($val['product_description'])) {
        $html = $val['product_description'];

        // proccess
        $dom->loadHTML($html);
        foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('td') as $i => $td) {
            if ($i % 2 == 0) {
                $label = strtolower(trim($td->nodeValue));
                $label = str_replace('-', ' ', trim($label, ':'));
            } else {
                $product_description[$label] = trim($td->nodeValue);
            }
        }
    }
    $val['product_description'] = $product_description;

    // ... rest
}

libxml_clear_errors();
libxml_use_internal_errors($dom_err);
```

**Example:**

https://3v4l.org/vECil

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [processor] => Intel Core 2 Duo - E8400
    [clock speed] => 3.0 GHz
    [memory] => 4 GB
    [hard disk] => 250 GB
    [video adapter] => VGA, Display
    [netwerk card] => 1000 Mbps LAN
    [optical drive] => DVD-Rewriter
    [operating system] => Windows 7 or 10 Pro
    [warranty] => 1 year
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2326239/5245032

```
<?php
$str = "This is  a string       with
spaces, tabs and newlines present";

$stripped = preg_replace(array('/\s{2,}/', '/[\t\n]/'), ' ', $str);

echo $str;
echo "\n---\n";
echo "$stripped";
?>
```

This outputs

```
This is  a string   with
spaces, tabs and newlines present
---
This is a string with spaces, tabs and newlines present
```

Answer (score 0):

Given an array that appears as follows:

```
<?php

$a = [ 0 => [ "product_id" => 219,
              "product_description" => "<table style=\"color:; text-align: left;\">
<tr>
<td>
Processor:
</td>
<td>
        Intel Core 2 Duo - E8400
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Clock speed:
</td>
<td>
        3.0 GHz
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Memory:
</td>
<td>
        4 GB
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Hard disk:
</td>
<td>
        250 GB
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Video-adapter:
</td>
<td>
        VGA, Display
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Netwerk card:
</td>
<td>
        1000 Mbps LAN
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Optical drive:
</td>
<td>
        DVD-Rewriter
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Operating system:
</td>
<td>
        Windows 7 or 10 Pro
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Warranty:
</td>
<td>
        1 year
</td>
</tr>
</table>"]
     ];
```

You may use the [DOM](http://htmlparsing.com/php.html) to pase it or other [libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php). Also, the string value may be processed using a variety of PHP built-in functions, as illustrated in this example:

```
<?php

$arr = array_pop($a);
$str =  $arr["product_description"];

$stripped = strip_tags( $str, "<td>" );
$replaced = str_replace( "</td>", "", $stripped );
$arr = explode( "<td>", $replaced );
array_shift( $arr );

$arrKeyVal=[];

for( $i=0, $max = count( $arr ); $i < $max; $i+=2 ) {
       $key = trim( $arr[$i],"\r\t\n :" );
       $arrKeyVal[strtolower( $key )] = trim( $arr[$i+1] );
}
print_r( $arrKeyVal );
```

See [live code](https://3v4l.org/vlWaP)

The code uses array_pop() to extract the nested associative array.  The "product_description" element's value is assigned to $str for easier handling.  The  string is stripped of all tags except the "<td>".  The closing td tag is replaced by an empty string.  The string is then split on the opening td tag.  The resulting array has an initial element that is empty so it is shifted off the array.  Then the code uses a loop to construct an associative array such that based on an array element's parity it is either a key or a value in the array. Also, every element of $arr is trimmed so that superfluous white space is removed as well as the trailing colon. And, strtolower() makes sure that every key appears in lowercase.

Using a regex is generally inadvisable; see [here](https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/).

Comment: Thanks, a dom parser is indeed the way to go. I did had to change it a bit for example: $dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8')); and then to remove the nbsp charachters in the foreach loop  $td->nodeValue = preg_replace( "~\x{00a0}~siu", "", $td->nodeValue ); and now I have it as I wanted.