# How to strip only multiple whitespace in a string PHP

Tags: php, split

I want to remove only multiple white space in a string.

Example:

> I am Mert Inal , so[multible white space here]I[multible white space here]can do that

It's must be:

> I am Mert Inal soIcan do that

Comment: are you sure you want `so I can` to become `soIcan`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove multiple whitespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326125/remove-multiple-whitespaces)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `preg_replace` with the pattern `\s{2,}`, and replace with empty string:

```
$input = "I am Mert Inal , so    I    can do that";
$output = preg_replace("/\s{2,}/", "", $input);
echo $output;
```

This outputs:

```
I am Mert Inal , soIcan do that
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
$string = "I am Mert Inal , so  I   ";

echo preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ',$string);
```

Output:

```
I am Mert Inal , so I .
```

Note:
/s is also applicable for \n\r\t.