# how to merge two models of regex patterns?

Tags: php, regex

Let's say I have a string.

```
`$str = "   Hi, my  name is 
         Petr"; `
```

Expecting: `$str = " Hi, my name is Petr";`

I need to replace all the white spaces '....' at the beginning of the string and then if there is a multiple number of white space between words in the string then replace it with one empty space.

I want to do this with the regex function 'preg_replace'.

But I don't know how to `"/^\s+/"` for remove white spaces on the start of string and `"/\s+/"` for white spaces between words in a string. 
Is it possible to merge the two formula patterns into one pattern? If so, what would the formula look like?

Comment: What do you want to do with the newline in the string? leave it intact?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326125/remove-multiple-whitespaces

Comment: Let's say I apply these regexes to the array where the client's home address is included. @Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to achieve this. You can take advantage of the fact that [`preg_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) can take an array of patterns and replacements to use your two regexes:

```
$str = "   Hi, my  name is 
         Petr";
echo preg_replace(array('/^\s+/', '/\s+/'), array('', ' '), $str) . "\n";
```

Alternatively, you can use a slightly more complicated regex using a positive lookbehind to remove any sequence of whitespace that is preceded by either the start of string (`^`) or other whitespace:

```
echo preg_replace('/(?<=^|\s)\s+/', '', $str);
```

In both cases the output is

```
Hi, my name is Petr
Hi, my name is Petr
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/hk8AS)

Comment: Thank you for help. I will try both your methods. @Nick

Comment: @PetrFořtFru-Fru no worries - but you shouldn't accept an answer until after you've had a chance to test it.

Comment: Do not worry. I've already tried both regexes. I used the easier method. So far I'm trying to understand regexes, I'm learning. Thanks again. @Nick

Comment: Please, I still have a question about regex. Can this regex be applied in MariaDB SQL? MariaDB has a function REGEXP_REPLACE but probably I'm not good enough to write a functional regex for MariaDB. Thank you. @Nick

Comment: @PetrFořtFru-Fru yes, you just need to use a nested `regexp_replace`, and escape the backslashes: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=143b6668305f42b0dc16266f84ee8372

Answer (score 1):

I guess,

```
$str = '   Hi, my  name is
         Petr';
$result = preg_replace('/\s{2,}/', ' ', $str);
$result = preg_replace('/^\s*|\s*$/', '', $result);

echo $result;
```

might work OK, which'd output:

```
Hi, my name is Petr
```